# Operator '&' is not defined for type 'string' and 'system.guid'

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have some VB code trying to execute a sql in a function

```
Public Shared Function getBackgroundInfo(ByVal aID As Guid) As pd_ABC

    Dim SQLCMD As New SqlCommand
    Dim BackgroundInfoDS As New DataSet()

    SQL = "select * from tblABC where ID = '" & aID & "'"
```

.....

both my ID and aID is GUID type,
but visual studio shows an error on where `ID = '" & aID & "'"`
I wonder if there is a better way to do this? Or do I need to use parameterized query?
Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: The compiler explicitly tells you what’s wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"select * from tblABC where ID = '"` is a string, `aID` is a guid.

When you add `aID` into your string, use `aID.ToString()`.

I would definitely recommend a parameterized version of your code though - for safety, code quality and general good practice.

Comment: Thanks for that! That's very helpful! I also have  ID = Session("Selected"), get value from dropdownlist selection. When I set ID to be GUID type , errors occur saying "Specified cast is not valid." Is there a way to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `ToString()` on `Guid` instance to get string representation of a guid:

```
SQL = "select * from tblABC where ID = '" & aID.ToString() & "'"
```

And answering your other question

> *Or do I need to use parameterized query?*

You don't need to, but you probably should. It's safer and more readable to use parameterized queries.

Comment: I think there's no reason to not use parameterized queries. It's always better to use them.

Comment: @Szymon That's exactly what I said. You don't have to use it, but it's better to do that.

Comment: I personally wouldn't say "You don't need to". Technically that's correct. But it's just not something that should be ever recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the advice very much! Though I don't know that I can only vote once~